# excel retain first value in range of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel Help:
How to find middle value in excel given 35-39 lbs. I want the answer as 37(Middle number in range)?

For Example in Column A below:

```
A  
----      
35- 39 lbs    
40- 45 lbs
```

The answer should be

```
A  
----
37  
43
```

And How to retain only the first value for above example

```
A
----  
35   
40
```

Comment: In the comments in the answers below you suggest that you are not merely just averaging two values. You say "They are not similar range of values" or " I don't always have 5 numbers as fixed in range, some cells have 5 or 10 number range for ex: 35-39 or 40-49" Can you explain how your data is structured. Maybe give us an example of a few of your "thousands" of ranges.

Comment: just use a series of CTRL+H, eg first replace dot with a coma. then another replacement to remove the spaces. finally go to the data tab and convert text to columns using the comma as separator.

Answer (score 0):

One is the "Average" `=Average(35,39)`=37 and the other is the "Min" `=Min(40,43)` =40. If you want the physical middle number in a group like '35,36,37,40,43' you can use "Median" `=median(35,36,37,40,43)` = 37

Comment: But it works for only 1 row, there are 1000's of row, with different values? How to calculate for all?

Comment: If the values 35 is in A1 and the value 39 is in B1, then in C1 put `=Average(A1:B1)`. If there are similar ranges of values in A2 and B2, then again in A3 and B3, then copy the formula down so it can compute the Average for each row.

Comment: Thanks. But they are not similar range of values? How to automate using a single formula?

Comment: What do you mean "They are not similar range of values"? Is it always two values like 40,50 or 23,64? `=average()` doesn't care. Do you mean there are sometimes more than two values that need to be averaged? How is the data structured in your sheet. Are the values all in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

One option is as follows

Say Cell **A1** = `35- 39 lbs`

In **B1**, type = `=MID(A1,1,2)` to extract `35`.

Then, in **C1**, type `=MID(A1,5,2)` to extact `39`.

In **D1** for instance, you can now average **C1** and **B1** with `=AVERAGE(B1, C1)`.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't  always have 5 numbers as fixed in range, some cells have 5  or 10 number range for ex: 35-39 or 40-49. How to automate my formula to it?

Comment: @SushmaPatil What problem did you run into when you tried the offered solution?  Be specific.